# Not adding Percentage, when I used "Computed Column" for Percentage Field

Tags: sql-server-2017

[Not adding Percentage, when I used "Computed Column" for Percentage Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16YQ0.png)

I try to calculate the percentage of the student marks using "Computed Column" but I'm unable to do that
Can any one please tell me where I did the mistake to calculate the percentage

thanks in advance .

Comment: Your design is denormalized, those 5 columns should be rows in a separate table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting 0 because you are working only with `integers`

If you divide by `125.0` it will force SQL Server to implicitely cast values to a decimal using order-of-precedence.